# flow to get .json output from a document extraction model

Tags: power-automate

I have created a model for document extraction in Microsoft PowerAutomate > Models, and then I have created a flow that is using this model.

Currently, I have 2 steps in this flow (1) "When a file is created" (I am using my OneDrive folder and (2) "Extract information from documents" (using the document extraction model I have created). From here, can someone please advise how I can create an output to my Onedrive folder and create the .json file containing key-value pairs for the fields extracted and also the original pdf file

Comment: What’s the issue exactly?